# bad bind variable in trigger

Tags: oracle, trigger

i'm trying to update the table whenever complaint has been registered

```
create or replace trigger complaint_advertise
    BEFORE INSERT ON COMPLAINT_INFO FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE BEGIN
    UPDATE ADVERTISEMENT SET AD_APPEAR='INVALID' WHERE AD_ID=NEW:AD_ID
    END;
```

But, getting error `ERROR at line 2: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'AD_ID'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code should read:

```
create or replace trigger complaint_advertise
BEFORE INSERT ON COMPLAINT_INFO FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
    UPDATE ADVERTISEMENT SET AD_APPEAR='INVALID' WHERE AD_ID=:NEW.AD_ID;
END;
/
```